# Where do I set the Nexus credentials for an Azure DevOps pipeline on a Maven project hosted on Bitbucket?

Tags: java, maven, bitbucket, azure-pipelines, nexus

I'm trying to create a simple Pipeline for a Java project that uses Maven. The .jar dependencies of my project are all hosted on an online Nexus that is password protected. The sources I am building are hosted on Bitbucket.

I can't seem to find how to tell the pipeline what credentials to use for Nexus.

This is my maven task result:

```
Downloaded from central: xxx (34 kB at 1.3 MB/s)
Downloading from nexus: xxx
Downloading from central: xxx
Downloading from nexus: xxx
Downloading from central: xxx
Downloading from nexus: xxx
Downloading from central: xxx 949 B

Downloaded from central: xxx (949 B at 45 kB/s)
Downloading from nexus: xxx
Downloading from central: xxx
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.979 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-01-16T19:17:43Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project webconfigurable: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.fenplast:webconfigurable:jar:1.3.0: Failed to collect dependencies at org.jscience:com.netappsid.org.jscience:jar:3.2.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.jscience:com.netappsid.org.jscience:jar:3.2.0: Could not transfer artifact org.jscience:com.netappsid.org.jscience:pom:3.2.0 from/to nexus (https://repository.fenplast.net/repository/public): Authentication failed for https://repository.fenplast.net/repository/public/org/jscience/com.netappsid.org.jscience/3.2.0/com.netappsid.org.jscience-3.2.0.pom 401 Unauthorized -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
The process '/usr/share/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin/mvn' failed with exit code 1
Could not retrieve code analysis results - Maven run failed.
No test result files matching /home/vsts/work/1/s/**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml were found, so publishing JUnit test results is being skipped.
##[error]Build failed.
Finishing: Maven
```

It says Authentication failed and Unauthorized.
When I run a build from my own machine locally it does work because I have a settings.xml file in my .m2 folder with the credentials but how do I make it work from Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a try using **Maven Authenticate** task add a maven [service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to connect to your external maven repositories. Below steps is for reference.

> Go to **Project settings** --> **Pipelines** --> Click **Service connections** --> Click **new service connection** --> select **Maven** --> Enter the required information for your Nexus Repository.

[image]

> Then in your pipeline Add **[Maven Authenticate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/maven-authenticate?view=azure-devops)** task before your **Maven task** to provides credentials for the external Maven repositories which will be used in the following maven task.

Since you only need authentication for external nexus maven repositories, you can leave **Feeds** field blank. And Then click below highlighted dropdown list to select the maven service connection for nexus you created in above steps.

[image]

When you finish above steps, your maven task should be able to download jar dependencies from nexus.

Comment: Sound exactly like what I'm looking for! I'll try that, thanks!

Comment: @Levi Lu-MSFT What about running the maven task in a docker container? is the runner authorized? Because i am getting still 401 in the docker container although i followed your steps in the answer.